# Disable / suspend Azure Time Series Insight

Tags: azure, azure-timeseries-insights

Since the pricing does not offer much choice in terms of flexibility my developer MSDN account is quickly running out of credits using Azure Time Series Insights fro a Proof of Concept. Is it somehow possible to suspend the service so no costs are incurred? I would hate to have to delete the whole thing and set it up again when we start working again on the PoC.

Comment: what happened, how did you approach your challenge?

Comment: I guess unaccepting my answer means that you found a way to disable/suspend TSI environment. Could you share it?

Comment: Hmm I don't recall unaccepting the answer. afaik there is still no other way than to completely remove and recreate an TSI environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, Azure still do not provide a way to suspend TSI environment.

Maybe you can use scripted template deployment for creating/deleting TSI environment.
With this approach, however, you are going to constantly loose your data.

On the link below there are guidelines, provided by Microsoft, on how to implement template deployment:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/time-series-insights/time-series-insights-manage-resources-using-azure-resource-manager-template

The general steps provided by MSFT are:

- Install PowerShell
- Create the template and a parameter file.
- In PowerShell, log in to your Azure account.
- Create a new resource group if one does not exist.
- Test the deployment.
- Deploy the template.

Comment: I may be alone in this opinion, but I thought the article above wasn’t very clear in explaining how to create a template based on an existing resource. In order create and view a template and parameter file for an existing (Time Series Insight) resource, navigate to your resource and select “Automation script” under the “Settings” section of the resource menu.

Comment: the url is for creating a template from "scratch", nevertheless your suggestion is a very good approach